# Simple and powerful chart LIB in PHP 5

Tags: php, charts

Recently I need to make a chart of employees' workload.Any recommendation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenFlashChart is kinda nice I have used it before just encode the data to json in php.. :)

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/

Or if you wan't to go JS..

http://g.raphaeljs.com/

highcharts is cool too if you have some money to spend :)

http://highcharts.com

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [pchart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/). Very clean, easy to install and use. The examples and documentation are great.
I also love the look of the graphs that it generates out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Google's chart API allows you to just call a URL with the data and it returns an image. I highly recommend using it (I do):

http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/

Answer (score 2):

[jpgraph](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/) is also a very nice, powerful and easy to implement chart library build using PHP. It is capable of drawing Each and every type of graph. With proper documentation and examples.

Comment: The Link changed: http://jpgraph.net/